# Is there a way to parse json into the desired output in pandas?

Tags: json, pandas

I am stuck in my code. I am parsing 'Json' using pandas but while transforming there is one column that I am stuck with. This column below is "json" inside a list. I want to transform it to 4 columns and the the corresponding data in the rows. The column name is "TypeValues". If I use, pd.concat to transform, I get the error message: "DataFrame constructor not properly called!". I tried using the "pd.DataFrame(eval(data))" but that gives me " eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object".

There is another column ID. For each ID, i have this below type of data in the "TypeValues" column. I want to get the transformed data with each ID. Does someone have an idea, how can I achieve this? (moreover, some of the rows of the column "TypeValues" have entries [] & blanks)

The column is in the comments section as it didn't allow me to post directly
Thanks in advance

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json from pathlib
import Path from pandas.io.json
import json_normalize import ast
#Reading the File data = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')

Data1 = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in data['TypeValues'].pop('TypeValues').items()})).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

This returns the error of incorrectly using the Dataframe

Comment: [{'Month': 1, 'Year': 2007, 'Category': 'A', 'Value': 10}, 
{'Month': 3, 'Year': 2007, 'Category': 'B', 'Value': 14}, 
{'Month': 12, 'Year': 2008, 'Category': 'A', 'Value': 18},
 {'Month': 6, 'Year': 2009, 'Category': 'A', 'Value': 20}, 
{'Month': 7, 'Year': 2010, 'Category': 'B', 'Value': 8}, 
{'Month': 9, 'Year': 2001, 'Category': 'A', 'Value': 7}]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited the post. Can you get the idea?